# What is the difference between attended POS and unattended POS

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

What is the difference between attended POS and unattended POS.
I cannot get the sense role of the word attended and unattended.

Are they different devices? Please, provide clear explanation  if possible with some images.

Thank you!

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen Do you mean that attended POS is the device that should include a person? Give some extended picture please. Is this person  a cardholder or a seller in the shop?

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen For example if there is some POS where I can use my credit card and there is NO ANY STAFF/PERSONAL is this an unattended POS?

Comment: @Dimi.  Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about retail hardware, not English.

Comment: @DanBron You are don't right, man.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen Thank you for your clear explanation. Please, convert your comment to an answer.

Comment: I've extracted the point my comments and put into an answer. I've subsequently deleted the comments to not clutter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attended means it's staffed/manned by a person. Unattended subsequently means not. To illustrate think of petrol/gas stations - which can be attended or unattended.

When the POS is staffed - there's a person there controlling the POS. It's attended.
When it's just you doing self-service, scanning your own wares or similar, and no staff is around - it's unattended.
That's why I used the petrol station example because a lot of them are just fuel pumps with no staff - so they're unattended

Comment: Person like you is really a good one and has big soul to help who need it. Thank you!